# AJAX POST return data not appearing

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an AJAX call which runs on a form submit (with prevent default to stop standard submit):

```
var form = $(this);
$.ajax({
    type: form.attr('method'),
    url: form.attr('action'),
    data: form.serialize()
}).done(function(data) {
    $('#processingFile').hide();
    $('#downloadFile').show();

    $('#shareURL').val(data.url);
    $('#downloadFile').attr('href', data.url);
    $('#aboutFile').html('<b>File URL:</b> ' + data.url + '<br /><b>File Size:</b> ' + data.size + '<br /><b>Time Stamp:</b> ' + data.timestamp + '<br /><b>Client IP:</b> ' + data.ip);
}).fail(function() {
    $('#saveFile').hide();
    $('#error').show();
});
```

The file it submits to is a PHP file which is as follows:

```
// VARIABLES
$fileURL = $_POST['fileURL'];
$tmpURL = substr(md5(rand()), 0, 7);
$deleteCode = md5($tmpURL);

// COOKIE
setcookie($tmpURL, $deleteCode, time()+86400);

// SAVE FILE
if($fileURL){
    file_put_contents("tmp/" . $tmpFile, file_get_contents("http://" . $fileURL));
}

// OUTPUT
$result = array(
    'url' => "tmp/" . $tmpFile,
    'size' => filesize("tmp/" . $tmpFile) * .0009765625 * .0009765625,
    'timestamp' => date('H:i:s d-m-Y'),
    'ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
);

echo json_encode($result);
```

When the script is run everywhere which uses `data.x` in the jQuery returns undefined. Any idea why that happens and how to fix it?

Comment: trying adding `header('Content-Type: application/json');` before your echo.

Comment: Please take a loot at your Firebug console (or Chrome inspector console), you will see the response sent by your PHP script. You may have an error in your PHP script, and add "dataType" parameter to your Ajax request (dataType: 'json').

Comment: instead of form.serialize() did you mean to use serializeArray()?

Answer (score 3):

`data` is a string containing your returned JSON text; it isn't an object.

To parse the JSON object, you have a couple of options:

- Call `JSON.parse()` yourself.
- Pass `dataType: "json"` to tell jQuery AJAX to parse it for you.
- Set `Content-Type: application/json` in the server's response so that jQuery knows to parse it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Set dataType: 'json' and check! Look this [doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) and set your datType.